# Using awk to split text file every 10,000 lines

Tags: awk

I have a large gzip'd text file.  I'd like to something like:

```
zcat BIGFILE.GZ | \
    awk (snag 10,000 lines and redirect to...) | \
    gzip -9 smallerPartFile.gz
```

the awk part up there, I basically want it to take 10,000 lines and send it to gzip and then repeat until all lines in the original input file are consumed.  I found a script that claims to do this, but when I run it on my files and then diff the original to the ones that were split and then merged, lines are missing. So, something is wrong with the awk part and I'm not sure what part is broken.

The goal:

- Read through the source file one time for the entire operation
- Split the source into smaller parts, delimited by newline.  Say, 10,000 lines per file
- Compress the target files that are created as a result of the split action and do so without an extra step after this script processes.

Here's the code.  Can someone tell me why this doesn't yield a file that can be split and merged and then diff'd to the original successfully?

```
# Generate files part0.dat.gz, part1.dat.gz, etc.
# restore with: zcat foo* | gzip -9 > restoredFoo.sql.gz (or something like that)
prefix="foo"
count=0
suffix=".sql"

lines=10000 # Split every 10000 line.

zcat /home/foo/foo.sql.gz |
while true; do
  partname=${prefix}${count}${suffix}

  # Use awk to read the required number of lines from the input stream.
  awk -v lines=${lines} 'NR <= lines {print} NR == lines {exit}' >${partname}

  if [[ -s ${partname} ]]; then
    # Compress this part file.
    gzip -9 ${partname}
    (( ++count ))
  else
    # Last file generated is empty, delete it.
    rm -f ${partname}
    break
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest doing all the house-keeping inside `awk`, this works here with GNU awk:

```awk
BEGIN { file = "1" }

{ print | "gzip -9 > " file ".gz" }

NR % 10000 == 0 {
  close("gzip -9 > " file ".gz")
  file = file + 1
}
```

This will save 10000 lines to `1.gz`, the next 10000 to `2.gz`, etc. Use `sprintf` if you want more flexibility in filename generation.

#### Updated with a test

Test data used are primes up to 300k, found [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17110900/primes).

```
wc -lc primes; md5sum primes
```

Output:

```
25997 196958 primes
547d527ec50c2799fa6ce96dba3c26c0  primes
```

Now, if the awk program above was saved into `split.awk` and run like this (with GNU awk):

```
awk -f split.awk primes
```

Three files (1.gz, 2.gz and 3.gz) are produced. Testing these files:

```
for f in {1..3}; do gzip -dc $f.gz >> foo; done
```

Test:

```
diff source.file foo
```

Output should be nothing if the files are the same.

And the same tests as above:

```
gzip -dc [1-3].gz | tee >(wc -lc) >(md5sum) > /dev/null
```

Output:

```
25997  196958
547d527ec50c2799fa6ce96dba3c26c0  -
```

This shows that the contents are the same and that the files are split as expected.

Comment: this seems to always trim off the last 34 characters of the last line for each split file.

Comment: Sounds odd. I've added an example to the answer, see if you get the same result.

Comment: Thanks Thor! I had to change the for loop because i had a lot of split files, but diff is telling me the original and the split files, then merged file are the same.

Comment: @Thor: you are right in the unlikely case the limit is exceeded. But then you must `close("gzip -9 > " file ".gz")` not only `close(file)`. Otherwise awk has no clue what to close.

Comment: @sparkie: You're right `close(file)` was incorrect. The likelihood of this being a problem depends on file size, number of available file descriptors and how many lines go into each file; it's cleaner to close each file as we're done with it.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that `awk` is reading its input (the pipe from `zcat`, in this case) a block at a time (where a block is 512 bytes, or a multiple thereof, depending on your OS).  So, by the time it has the 10000th newline character (end-of-line marker) in memory, it also has the 10001st line, the 10002nd, and quite probably more (or possibly less) in memory, too.  This is a problem because it means those characters have been read out of the pipe, and are no longer available for the next iteration of `awk` to read.

Comment: That makes sense.  Hmm.  Is there a way to capture those and buffer them and achieve the desired result? btw, this is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

The shorter (and more useful) answer: have you looked at the Unix `split` command?

Comment: yes I know about split and that isn't useful.  A careful reader will notice that split generates uncompressed files.  I need them compressed.

Comment: The problem with split is that until he finishes with every piece of the split he can't start compressing split output, thus if dealing with a huge gzip split could be just not possible to use.

Comment: @Valor - exactly.  I have 400 of these files, each is about 400GB uncompressed. :(

Comment: @Valor: Well, @Sneaky could run a shell script in parallel with the `split`, that waits until `fooab` is created, and then zips `fooaa`, then waits until `fooac` is created, and then zips `fooab`, and so on.  But that’s a kluge, and not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Sneaky: I would quibble that the number of files isn’t a factor.  Yes, the size obviously is.  But if you have about 401GB free space, I don’t see why you couldn’t use `split`.  …  But wait — does that mean that you expect to break each file into _millions_ of pieces (400G ÷ 80 = 5000000)?  That might rule out `split` — I don’t know whether it can handle more than 676 (26²) output files.

Comment: @SneakyWombat I think I've it... give me a minute

Answer (score 3):

I thought about it and found a way, not efficient at all, which will useless decompress entirely each file to take each piece, meaning that if you want to split in 20 pieces, it will decompress the big files 20 times. But it won't store the whole file, only the compressed piece, so while it's storage efficient it's cpu inefficient.

Script should be run with first argument the big gzip file and second argument the number of lines to split.

```
#!/bin/bash
GZIP_FILE=$1
SPLIT_LINES=$2
TOTAL_LINES=`zcat $GZIP_FILE|wc -l`
START=0
NEXT_START=0
while [ $NEXT_START -lt $TOTAL_LINES ]; do
        NEXT_START=$(( $NEXT_START + $SPLIT_LINES ))
        echo .
        zcat $GZIP_FILE|sed -n ${START},${NEXT_START}p |gzip -9 > ${GZIP_FILE}.lines-${START}-${NEXT_START}.gz
        START=$NEXT_START
done
```

This will create in the same dir for each piece a file named as the gzip file and appending ".lines-$startline-$endline.gz"

Hope you are ok wasting CPU :)

Comment: I was going to say that next!  :)

Comment: you guys are hilarious.  I think I'll try to script something through python or something.  The idea was was to read through the source file one time, splitting it as it's read.  The TOTAL_LINES var will read through the entire file to get the count and then it goes through the business end of the work. Haha.  I'll give you an up vote for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You have an awk alternative. Here is how you could do it with GNU split or GNU parallel.

GNU split has a `--filter` option and something very close to what you are trying to do is described in the manual:

```
`--filter=COMMAND'
     With this option, rather than simply writing to each output file,
     write through a pipe to the specified shell COMMAND for each
     output file.  COMMAND should use the $FILE environment variable,
     which is set to a different output file name for each invocation
     of the command.  For example, imagine that you have a 1TiB
     compressed file that, if uncompressed, would be too large to
     reside on disk, yet you must split it into individually-compressed
     pieces of a more manageable size.  To do that, you might run this
     command:

          xz -dc BIG.xz | split -b200G --filter='xz > $FILE.xz' - big-

     Assuming a 10:1 compression ratio, that would create about fifty
     20GiB files with names `big-xaa.xz', `big-xab.xz', `big-xac.xz',
     etc.
```

So in your case you could do:

```
zcat bigfile.gz | split -l 10000 --filter='gzip -9 > $FILE.gz' - big-
```

A good alternative to split would be to use GNU parallel, this would allow you to parallelize the compression:

```
zcat bigfile.gz | parallel --pipe -N 10000 'gzip > {#}.gz'
```